# How to remove one characters of an array with json_encode and mysql

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, arrays

I develop a drawing system and I have a little problem, I have one var into json_encode because I use MySQL and the line of result is:

30,Richard,Léa

29,Brown,Mike

I want to delete all commas of the line of result, but it's impossible.

This is my code:

```
$query = "SELECT id, nom, prénom FROM membres";
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query);
$products = []; // new array
while($product = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_NUM)) {
    $products[] = $product ; // push into array
}

var names = <?php echo json_encode($products) ?>;
```

When I want to use the replace function, I have nothing into my var "names" and no result to print.

```
var x;
for(x = 0; x < 10; x++){
    names[x] = names[x].replace(',', ' ');
}
```

Comment: try it : `names[x] = names[x].replace(/,/g, ' ');`

Comment: `names` should be an array of arrays, such that `names[x]` is an array. There wouldn't be commas between the values unless you are just looking at the raw json output or you tried to print the array as a string, eg `element.innerHTML=names[x]` in which case the default toString method of the array is used to build a string version of the array which does a `.join(',')`

Comment: @AnantKumarSingh doesn't work... nothing to print

Comment: If `names` is somehow empty, that's the issue, not removing or replacing characters from a string. The sample is not enough to reproduce the issue.